# Can a magus use spellstrike on an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, opportunity-attack, magus

A magus casts *Shocking Grasp*, uses the arcane pool (for +1) and walks into battle. The baddie runs past the Magus, and the Magus gets an attack of opportunity, can he use Spellstrike and deliver the *Shocking Grasp*?

The rules seem silent on this--but my gut tells me that they would be able to discharge the spell through an AoO because it is a **melee attack** (if they hit). I just want to see if there are any rules or rulings on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, a magus can use spellstrike with an attack of opportunity.

An [FAQ from Paizo designer Sean Reynolds](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5ld3d?FAQ-Attack) specifically states that once a magus with Spellstrike has cast a touch spell they can continue to hold the charge and deliver the spell with a melee attack later. Once their hand or weapon touches something the spell is discharged, but until that time they can deliver the spell with a melee touch attack or a melee attack, which would include an attack of opportunity.

Comment: Ex-designer, for the record.